# Shopify API orders data

Tags: python, api, postman, shopify, shopify-app

I want to fetch Shopify orders data in any given range but not able to do so

The code is written below:

I have used postman to call the get requests

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://{apikey}:{passcode_with_token}@{store_name}/admin/api/2022-10/orders.json?status=any"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer token_value'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Do you pass a token value?

Comment: Yes in place of token_value  I just didn't wrote the real value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this library https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api

Furthermore, to retrieve orders between a certain period I suggest you to use graphql instead of the REST api.

To give you an example

```
{
    orders(query:"created_at:>='2022-01-01T00:00:00BST' AND created_at:<='2022-12-31T23:59:59BST')", sortKey: CREATED_AT, reverse: true, first: 20) {
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
            cursor
            node {
                createdAt
                name
                lineItems(first: 20) {
                    pageInfo {
                        hasNextPage
                    }
                    edges {
                        cursor
                        node {
                            variant {
                                title
                                inventoryQuantity
                            }
                            sku
                            title
                            quantity
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
shopify.Session.setup(api_key=client_id, secret=client_secret)
if password: # depending if you have a password (private app) or access token (custom/public app)
    shopify_session = shopify.Session(store, api_version, password)
else:
     shopify_session = shopify.Session(store, version=api_version, token=access_token)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(shopify_session)

def retrieve_orders():
    with open('query.graphql', 'r') as fp:
        query = fp.read()
    result =  json.loads(shopify.GraphQL().execute(query))
    # ...
    return resutl['edges']
```

Keep in mind that you have to handle pagination in the result (that would be the same with the REST api) and to retrieve orders older than 120 days (I can be wrong but is something similar) you need a specific permission.

Comment: Do i need to pass this above information which you have given as example in postman